# SELECT query for selecting all field and counting the contents of the fields

Tags: sql, oracle

Hello can anyone help me with a query where you select all columns and then count the content of the columns. Not sure how this could be achieved can someone shed some light on that.

For example I have a table that returns number of tickets but those tickets can be more than one so I would like to select all the tickets depending on a variable and then count the contents of it like this:

```
Booking ID | Tickets | variable
1              2         
2              1
3              5
```

How would I go about to count the contents of for example booking 1 and 3 so that the result will be 7

Thank you.

Comment: Edit your question (or ask another) with sample data and desired results.

Comment: Columns, not fields... Add table definition, sample table data, and the expected result.

Comment: edited the post @GordonLinoff

Comment: may be you could use group by?

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT SUM(Tickets) FROM your_table WHERE Booking_ID IN (1,3)
```